# Components tab missing Joomla 1.7 administratrion panel

Tags: tabs, components, joomla1.7, administrator

I am just tired of finding the solution of problem. I don't know how it gone wrong but my **Components tab** is not appearing in my Joomla admin panel.

screenshot;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmjVY.png

But the components are still accessible by using direct link like:

http://www.example.net/administrator/index.php?option=com_comprofiler

I don't want do reinstall whole Joomla because it took me 1 week to set it up all the things. I tried replacing some core files but it didn't helped. I am thinking to upgrade 1.7.1 to 1.7.3 may be it could fix. I would appreciate if anyone can get my Components tab back.

Thanks alot

Comment: Please help me. I am very new to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I reinstalled Joomla. And after that, the error was gone! Have you tried it?